# Can I use "PaymentMethodCreditCard" as paymentMethod?

Tags: schema.org, credit-card, json-ld

When creating a Order in schema.org syntax, I have `paymentMethod` with values like `http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PayPal` or `http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#DirectDebit` but for cards I don't want to specify the specific type of card (Visa, American Express, etc).

¿Should I use `http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PaymentMethodCreditCard` as value?

For example in JSON-LD:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Order",
  "merchant": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "My Company"
  },
  "orderNumber": "546846486",
  "orderStatus": "http://schema.org/OrderDelivered",
  "paymentMethod": "http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PaymentMethodCreditCard",
  "priceCurrency": "EUR",
  "price": "125.48",
  "acceptedOffer": {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "itemOffered": {
      "@type": "Product",
      "name": "Towel 42"
    "price": "125.48",
    "priceCurrency": "EUR",
    "eligibleQuantity": {
      "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
      "value": "1"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The GoodRelations vocabulary defines that [`gr:PaymentMethodCreditCard`](http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#PaymentMethodCreditCard) is a class, not an individual. (Schema.org’s [`CreditCard`](http://schema.org/CreditCard) is derived from this.)

The idea is to use individuals that are defined to be of this class, not the class itself.

There doesn’t seem to be an individual that represents *all* credit cards (and in practice it probably wouldn’t be a good idea to use such an individual).

You could list all supported credit cards explicitly:

```json
"paymentMethod": [
  {"@id": "http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#VISA"}, 
  {"@id": "http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#MasterCard"}, 
  {"@id": "http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#JCB"}
],
```

And if you support a credit card that hasn’t a predefined individual, you could define an individual yourself by making use of the `gr:PaymentMethodCreditCard`/`schema:CreditCard` types.